# Implementing anisotropic lighting for planar surfaces

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, 3d, glsl, webgl

I am trying to emulate some kind of specular reflections through anisotropy in my WebGL shader, something like this described in this tutorial [here](http://www.free3dtutorials.com/creating-a-stainless-steel-material.php).

I realized that while is easy to get convincing results with spherical shapes like the [Utah teapot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utah_teapot), it is somewhat more difficult to get nice looking lighting effects by implementing anisotropic lighting for planar or squared geometries.

After reading this paper [Anisotropic Lighting using HLS](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/Direct3D9/src/HLSL_Aniso/docs/HLSL_Aniso.pdf) from nVIDIA, I started playing with following shader:

```
vec3 surfaceToLight(vec3 p) {
    return normalize(p - v_worldPos);
}
vec3 anisoVector() {
    return vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
void main() {
    vec3 texColor = vec3(0.0);
    vec3 N = normalize(v_normal); // Interpolated directions need to be re-normalized 
    vec3 L = surfaceToLight(lightPos);
    vec3 E = anisoVector();
    vec3 H = normalize(E + L);
    vec2 tCoords = vec2(0.0);
    tCoords.x = 2.0 * dot(H, N) - 1.0; //The value varies with the line of sight
    tCoords.y = 2.0 * dot(L, N) - 1.0; //each vertex has a fixed value
    vec4 tex = texture2D(s_texture, tCoords);
    //vec3 anisoColor = tex.rgb; // show texture color only
    //vec3 anisoColor = tex.aaa; // show anisotropic term only
    vec3 anisoColor = tex.rgb * tex.aaa;
    texColor += material.specular * light.color * anisoColor;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texColor, u_opacity);
}
```

Here is what I get actually (geometries are without texture coordinates and without creased normals):

[image]

I am aware that I can't simply use the method described in the above mentioned paper for everything, but, at least, it seems to me a good starting point to achieve fast *simulated* anisotropic lighting.

Sadly, I am not able to fully understand the math used to create the texture and so I am asking if there is any method to either

- tweak the texture coordinates in this part of the fragment shader

  ```
  tCoords.x = 2.0 * dot(H, N) - 1.0;
  tCoords.y = 2.0 * dot(L, N) - 1.0;
  ```
- tweak the shape of the alpha channel inside the texture (below the RGBA layers and the result)

[image]

...to get nice-looking vertical specular reflections for planar geometries, like the cube on the right side.

Does anyone know anything about this?

---

BTW, if someone interested, pay attention that the texture shall be mirrored:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.MIRRORED_REPEAT);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.MIRRORED_REPEAT);
```

...and here is the texture as PNG (the original one from nVIDIA is in TGA format).

[image]